# How to iterate over a string using a buffer (python)

Tags: python, string, iteration, buffer

I'm trying to find some code that, given a string, will allow me to iterate over each line using the for loop construct, but with the added requirement that separate for loop constructs will not reset the iteration back to the beginning.

At the moment I have

```
sList = [line for line in theString.split(os.linesep)]
for line in SList
  ... do stuff
```

But successive for loops will reset the iteration back to the beginning.

Does something in python exist for this, or will I have to write one from scratch?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit with some examples? Do you e.g. want to break the loop before having iterated over everything and know where you are?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python
    import os
    
    theString = "abc\ndef"
    sList = [line for line in theString.split(os.linesep)]
    for line in sList:
        print line
        break
    
    for line in sList:
        print line
        break

Should print:  
abc  
def  

Not  
abc  
abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another iterator:

```
aList = range(10)
anIterator = iter(aList)

for item in anIterator:
    print item
    if item > 4: break

for item in anIterator:
    print item
```

Answer (score 13):

Just use a generator expression (genexp) instead of the list comprehension (listcomp) you're now using - i.e.:

```
sList = (line for line in theString.split(os.linesep))
```

that's all -- if you're otherwise happy with your code (splitting by os.linesep, even though normal text I/O in Python will already have translated those into `\n`...), all you need to do is to use parentheses (the round kind) instead of brackets (the square kind), and you'll get a generator instead of a list.

Now, each time you do a `for line in sList:`, it will start again from where the previous one had stopped (presumably because of a `break`) -- that's what you're asking for, right?

Comment: Ah, well done, sir.  Thanks for teaching me something about the newer python features.

Comment: What version of python was genexp introduced? We're using 2.2 at the moment, and I get a syntax error using your suggestion

Comment: @Taras, they came in with 2.4, a bit more than 5 years ago. An explicit call to `iter`, as in Federico's answer that you suggested, works in 2.2.  (If you need help about a version that's 5 releases and 5 years behind, indicating it in your questions will be far more useful than belatedly mentioning it in comments;-).

Comment: Point taken - will put the version information into my next question :*)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of slices and [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
sList = theString.split(os.linesep)
for i, line in enumerate(sList):
    if foo: 
        break

for j, line in enumerate(sList[i:]):
    # do more stuff
```

Comment: This will break with a NameError if `sList` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hack at an iterator?

```
def iterOverList(someList):
    for i in someList:
        # Do some stuff
        yield
```

Then just call iterOverList() within a loop a few times, it'll retain state?

Comment: Was hoping there was a simpler way! Looks like there is, see @Federico below